# How to shuffle questions and show one item of an array

Tags: swift, nsarray, plist

I've got a quiz project I'm working on, however at the moment I'm finding it hard to shuffle the questions and pick individual items from the array. Please find my code below.

My category choosing controller is:

```
struct Quiz {
private(set) var name = String()
private(set) var plist: NSArray



init(name: String) {
self.name = name
plist = NSArray(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "plist")!)!

}

static let quizzes = [Quiz(name: "Development"), Quiz(name: "Reflexes")]}
```

My quiz controller is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {    
super.viewDidLoad()


set = shuffledQuiz([[Quiz.quizzes[currentTopicIndex].plist]])

quiz = set.objectEnumerator()


pickQuestion()
}

func shuffledQuiz(_ name: [[NSArray]]) -> NSArray{
if currentSetIndex < name.count {
    return name[currentSetIndex].shuffled() as NSArray
}
return NSArray()}

func pickQuestion() {

if let quiz = quiz?.nextObject() as? NSArray {
    print(quiz)

    let questionLabel: [String] = quiz.value(forKeyPath: "question") as! NSArray as! [String]

    print(questionLabel)
    self.questionLabel.text = questionLabel.description

    let correctAnswer: [Int] = quiz.value(forKey: "Answer") as! NSArray as! [Int]
     print(correctAnswer)
    let answers = quiz.value(forKeyPath: "options") as! NSArray

   print(answers)


    for i in 0..<answersButtons.count {
        answersButtons[i].setTitle((answers[i] as AnyObject).localizedName, for: .normal)
    }
    remainingQuestionsLabel.text = "\(set.index(of: quiz) + 1)/\(set.count)"
}
else {
    endOfQuestionsAlert()
}
}
```

My plist is as follows

[image: Plist image is here]

I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle.

The basic algorithm is:

1. Start with your unshuffled array and an empty shuffled array.
2. Pick an element at random from the unshuffled array
3. Remove it from the unshuffled array and add it to the end of the shuffled array.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until the unshuffled array is empty.
5. Return the shuffled array.

You can shuffle an array "in place" using the following algorithm

1. set the variable n to the number of elements in the array.
2. pick a random number `x` in `0 ..< n` (use [arc4random_uniform()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/arc4random_uniform))
3. swap element `x` with element `n - 1`
4. subtract `1` from `n`
5. Repeat steps 2 to 4 until `n` is zero.